# Common Mode feedback in EEG systems

Tags: amplifier, feedback, common-mode, biopotential, eeg

EEG signals (potential from brain) contain 'noise' due to EMG signals (potential from muscles). I was thinking of using the EMG as a common mode feedback prior to the amplification of the EEG signal. Thus, I would assume the EMG signal (EEG 'noise) can be removed when it enters the differential amplifier.

I am just wondering how possible this is. I am aware that EMG signals are much larger than EEG signals.

Comment: I think this needs the EMG embedded in the EEG is the *exact* same as the EMG you're using as a reference. Is this the case?

Comment: Normally muscle noise is reduced on scalp with gavlanic noise and variable capacitance from lack of pressure By using silver oxide pads with pressure such as a baseball cap.

Comment: @Los Frikoles That's correct, The EEG and EMG system is identical, the only difference is the EMG electrodes are mounted directly to the 'noise' source, while the EEG is mounted in the scalp containing the required signal with the noise too.

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 So a stretchy rubber hemisphere that pushes the electrodes on to the scalp would be called a Vari-Cap?

Comment: or a Howie Mandel latex cap

Comment: A baseball cap with the battery , amplifier and short shielded wires to electrodes is best bet with an electrode for  0V or CM negative feedback for an active shield.

Comment: Interestingly, many moons ago I was in front of a poster at a Society for Neuroscience meeting, arguing with one of the early players in EEG-based brain machine interfaces.  The guy is quite famous in the field now.  I was arguing that he didn't do enough controls, and he didn't really know whether all of his results could have been EMG

Comment: 6 months later, SfN sent out a promo postcard, with a picture of me arguing with the guy.

Comment: Open EEG project http://openeeg.sourceforge.net/doc/

Answer (score 0):

No --  sounds like a good idea, but separating EEG and EMG is much easier said than done.  How do you intend to get  "pure"  EMG to use as your common Mode signal, especially if it shares a freq spectrum with EEG?

The real way to separate emg and eeg is filtering.  EEG is lower frequency than EMG.  What *isn't* low frequency, though, is movement artifact.  If the EMG activity is caused by movement, and the movement also causes motion in the electrode-skin interface, this can cause trouble.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm a little unsure about. I was maybe thinking that since the EMG signal is significantly larger than the EEG signal that it would be 'pure' enough. Is their any way I can set up a basic setup showing this. This is for my final year research study.

Comment: @NathanLe  my comment is your answer.  Suppress the noise by better sensing the physcial contacts with pressure and lower resistance.  The best signals require shaving hair and abrasion, but I don't think it is necessary.   Analyze the pad C and shunt R time constant to get RC<< 1 s with low ESR on contact

Comment: @Tony Stewart Thanks for your reply. However I was looking for some sort of original approach related to this setup for study for my research project

Comment: This is how I did it successfully this way with a good INA about 44 yrs ago, how far back did you want to go?  RL CM feedback is also used.

Comment: No I believe you that it's a proven method to use. But that is my point. For the purpose of my project, I wanted to talk about my approach of using 'EMG's as a common mode feedback for noise reduction' because it doesn't seem to have been done before. (I can discuss about the effectiveness etc. in my results evaluation)

Comment: Or do you mean your comment is an answer to Scotts question of attaining a 'pure' EMG signal?